# How do I add a style template for Report Wizard in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

We're using the report viewer for .rdlc files in an MVC application but at the moment we're manually setting the properties (fonts, heading background columns etc) for each report (each rdlc).

When using the report wizard (New Item / reporting / Report Wizard) in VS 2012, the very last wizard screen asks you to pick a style from (corporate, Forest, Generic, Mahogany, Ocean and Slate). My understanding is that I should be able to add my own style into that list, but can't seem to make that happen.

I've search my C: drive for StyleTemplates.xml and found 3 versions. I updated all three of them adding my own style, and when that didn't work changing the name of one of the existing styles, but it has no effect. I've restarted VS in case it's a caching thing, but no luck.

The posts I've found online so far refer to changing StyleTemplates.xml for VS 2010. Does it still work the same for 2012? Certainly doesn't seem to.

Many thanks,

Comment: Anyone got any suggestions on this? This is my first question on here, so if it's about an answer approval ratio, I don't have one because I'm new.